# Two forms in MVC3 cause unwanted refresh

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, postback

I'm currently building my first application in MVC3. In one of my views, there are 2 forms. One is only to select an image and show/upload it in the page using AJAX (calling another controler and using an hidden IFrame like in this [post](http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/2011/11/16/AJAX-File-Uploads-with-jQuery-and-MVC-3.aspx)). The other form is to enter information such as name, address, etc. Also, when an image is selected and imported using the first form, an hidden field is filled in the second form so that when the Create controler is called, everything is created in the database.

All of this works perfectly but if the user makes a mistake and enter text in a number field of the second form, the validation of my model is taken care and there is a postback showing the error in red. By doing so, the first form lose all information and is resetted with the file input control and no image shown.

Does anyone have an idea how to get around this problem? I'm very new to MVC3 and to AJAX so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

My final goal is that once the picture is shown in the page (and uploaded), it will stay there until the second form is validated and send to my Create controler.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Some people ask for the code, here it is!
This is the view:

```
@model RecettesMaison.Models.Recipe

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var isFirstLoad = true;
    var loadingImg;

    function UploadImage() {
        var fileUploader = document.getElementById("fileuploader");
        $(fileUploader).hide();

        //Create a new image and insert it into the Images div.  Just to be fancy, 
        //we're going to use a "FadeIn" effect from jQuery
        var imgDiv = document.getElementById("Images");
        loadingImg = new Image();
        loadingImg.src = "../../Pictures/ajax-loader.gif";

        //Hide the image before adding to the DOM
        $(loadingImg).hide();
        imgDiv.appendChild(loadingImg);
        //Now fade the image in
        $(loadingImg).fadeIn(500, null);

        $("#ImgForm").submit();
    }

    function UploadImage_Complete() {
        //Check to see if this is the first load of the iFrame
        if (isFirstLoad == true) {
            isFirstLoad = false;
            return;
        }

        //Reset the image form so the file won't get uploaded again
        document.getElementById("ImgForm").reset();

        //Grab the content of the textarea we named jsonResult .  This shold be loaded into 
        //the hidden iFrame.
        var newImg = $.parseJSON($("#UploadTarget").contents().find("#jsonResult")[0].innerHTML);

        //If there was an error, display it to the user
        if (newImg.IsValid == false) {
            alert(newImg.Message);
            return;
        }

        //Create a new image and insert it into the Images div.  Just to be fancy, 
        //we're going to use a "FadeIn" effect from jQuery
        var imgDiv = document.getElementById("Images");
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = newImg.ImagePath;
        img.name = "uploadedImage";


        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input.setAttribute("name", "Picture");
        input.setAttribute("id", "Picture");
        input.setAttribute("value", newImg.RealName);
        document.getElementById("Hidden").appendChild(input);

        //Hide the image before adding to the DOM
        $(img).hide();
        imgDiv.removeChild(loadingImg)
        imgDiv.appendChild(img);
        $(img).addClass('img-polaroid');

        //Now fade the image in
        $(img).fadeIn(500, null);
    }
</script>

<iframe id="UploadTarget" name="UploadTarget" onload="UploadImage_Complete();" style="position: absolute; left: -999em; top: -999em;"></iframe>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12">
            <h4>Publier une recette</h4>
            <div class="row-fluid">
              <div class="span3">

                @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Recipe", FormMethod.Post,
                    new
                    {
                        enctype = "multipart/form-data",
                        id = "ImgForm",
                        name = "ImgForm",
                        target = "UploadTarget"
                    }))
                {
                    <div id="fileuploader">
                    <input id="lefile" type="file" style="display:none" name="imageFile" accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg" />
                    <div class="input-append">
                       <input id="photoCover" class="input-large" type="text" />
                       <a class="btn" onclick="$('input[id=lefile]').click();">Parcourir...</a>
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $('input[id=lefile]').change(function () {
                            $('#photoCover').val($(this).val());
                        }); 
                    </script>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Sauvegarder l'image" onclick="UploadImage()" />
                    </div>

                    <div id="Images"></div>
                }
              </div>
              <div class="span9">
              @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Recipe", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "realForm", name = "realform" }))
              {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div id="Hidden"></div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecipeName) <div class="alert alert-info">Soyez original!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecipeName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecipeName)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Source) <div class="alert alert-info">(Exemple: Ricardo, Food Channel, Blog de Jean Cuisine, etc...)</div>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Source)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Source)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PreparationTime)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PreparationTime) minutes
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PreparationTime)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CookingTime)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CookingTime) minutes
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CookingTime)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MacerationTime)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MacerationTime) minutes
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MacerationTime)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Portions) <div class="alert alert-info">Combien d'adultes cette recettes peut nourir?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Portions)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Portions)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Commentary) <div class="alert alert-info">Partagez votre expérience avec cette recette, que ce soit au moment de sa création ou de sa préparation. <br />Dites les modifications que vous faites à la recette originale.<br />Rendez cette recettes personnelle! </div>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Commentary)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Commentary)
                </div>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Publier la recette!" />
                </p>
              }
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Here is the controller for the sending of the picture

```
[HttpPost]
public WrappedJsonResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileWrapper imageFile)
{

    if (imageFile == null || imageFile.ContentLength == 0)
    {
        return new WrappedJsonResult
        {
           Data = new
           {
                IsValid = false,
                Message = "No file was uploaded.",
                ImagePath = string.Empty
            }
        };
    }

    if (imageFile.ContentType != "image/jpeg" && imageFile.ContentType != "image/png")
    {
        return new WrappedJsonResult
        {
            Data = new
            {
                IsValid = false,
                Message = "Mauvais format de fichier!",
                ImagePath = string.Empty
            }
        };
    }

    int nIndexPoint = imageFile.FileName.IndexOf(".");
    string strExtension = imageFile.FileName.Substring(nIndexPoint + 1);

    var fileName = String.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), strExtension);

    var imagePathFull = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Pictures/Upload/FullSize")), fileName);
    var imagePathThumb = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Pictures/Upload/Thumbnail")), fileName);

    imageFile.SaveAs(imagePathFull);
    ThumbnailGenerator generator = new ThumbnailGenerator();
    generator.GetThumbnail(imagePathFull, imagePathThumb);

    return new WrappedJsonResult
    {
        Data = new
       {
            IsValid = true,
            Message = string.Empty,
            ImagePath = Url.Content(String.Format("~/Pictures/Upload/Thumbnail/{0}", fileName)),
            RealName = fileName
        }
    };
}
```

And finally, here is the controler called by the second form.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Recipe recipe)
{
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          db.Recipes.Add(recipe);
          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");  
      }

      return View(recipe);
}
```

Comment: Showing some of your code would help us to give you some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to have the image (or, it looks like, just the filename) as part of your recipe model, and store it in your second form in a Html.HiddenFor element.

Then you will need a document.ready jQuery function to see if a fliename is available, and display it if there is one.  Likely this should call the same function that you call when uploading is complete.

Finally, when uploading is complete in the ajax method, use jQuery to update the hidden field with the image filename, and now when you post back your model has all the info it needs to display a complete view, including the picture.

Make sense?

Comment: I will try this in 1 or 2 days (very buzy on other things right now). As far as I can tell, this makes sense but if you can add some code or pseudo-code to your answer, it may help me.

Comment: Thanks you so much!!! Even if you didn't provide any code, this was exactly what I needed. You deserve your 50 points :)

Comment: Wow thanks.  Kinda slammed right now so didn't get to it...but knew you could do it!